# Change Serializer behavior

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have serializer which contain nested object:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta():
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email')
```

And i have item:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta():
        fields = ('id', 'item_name', 'text')
```

When i send JSON on server, it return error: validation error, A user with that username already exists.
But i don't want create new user, I just want create copy Item for recieved user list.
I tried use `validate`, but it doesn't work.

**UPD**

View:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny)
    Model = Item
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    queryset = Item.objects
```

Result:

```
{
"errors": {
    "user": [
        {
            "username": [
                "A user with that username already exists."
            ]
        },
        {
            "username": [
                "A user with that username already exists."
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"detail": "Validation error"
```

}

Comment: Please show us the codes, specially how you used the serializer.

Comment: `I just want create copy Item for recieved user list` so you want to get user data by looking `username` in request  ?

Comment: I will send item data, and list of users. But I can't handle some validator, which check exist this user or not exist. It isn't validate in serializer.

Comment: use `def create(self, validated_data):`  . inside that check whether `username` with that User exists. if exists return that user.

Comment: It's not working, Patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `UserSerializer` is using the Django's auth `User` class, it will create a uniqueness check out of the model's constraint. Django's `User` do have a unique constraint set on the username.

To remove it, you'll need to change the `UserSerializer`.
First print a serializer instance to see what constraint there are:

```
serializer = UserSerializer()
print(serializer)
```

This should give you something similar to:

```
UserSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    username = CharField(help_text='Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=30, validators=[<django.core.validators.RegexValidator object>, <UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())>])
    email = EmailField(allow_blank=True, label='Email address', max_length=254, required=False)
```

As you can see, there's a `UniqueValidator` on `username`.

Let's change the validators for that field:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {'validators': []}
        }
```

And that should do.

Please note that it also remove the `RegexValidator` which is left to you depending on what you want to put there.

If you print the new serializer, you should get something such as:

```
UserSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    username = CharField(help_text='Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=30, validators=[])
    email = EmailField(allow_blank=True, label='Email address', max_length=254, required=False)
```